# Aheadworks Magento Blog extension List all posts

Tags: magento, blogs

Using AW blog extension and id like to get a list of all blog posts. Sounds simple right?

But i can't seem to figure out how i could do this? It seems that the controller gets the blog posts in a category from reading the category name in the url.

If anyones had any experience with the aheadworks blog extension (free) and might be able to help out that would be great.